# hex to string in javascript

Tags: javascript, hex

How can I convert:
from:
'`\\x3c`'
to:
'`<`';

I tried:

```
s=eval(s.replace("\\\\", ""));
```

does not work. How I do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) instead of `eval`, and `parseInt` using base 16:

```
s=String.fromCharCode(parseInt(s.substr(2), 16));
```

Comment: +1, a shorter alternative would be `String.fromCharCode(+("0"+s.slice(1)));`

Comment: @Andy Even shorter: `String.fromCharCode("0"+s.slice(1));`

Comment: @DigitalPlane: of course, `fromCharCode` casts to an int for you! doh! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, try this: `$('<div>').html('\x3c').text()`

Else (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript))

```
function htmlDecode(input){
  var e = document.createElement('div');
  e.innerHTML = input;
  return e.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, which will incur the wrath of people who believe that "`eval`" is unequivocally evil, is as follows:

```
var s = "\\x3c";
var s2 = eval('"' + s + '"'); // => "<"
```

Comment: I wouldn't say `eval` is *unequivocally* evil, but I would say that this isn't really an acceptable use of `eval` (since alternative options exist).

Comment: @Andy E: ok, I'll take the bait =)  I agree the `String.fromCharCode` is the right way but assuming we have validated the input (e.g. ensured it can only be an escaped character reference) then what's the potential harm in using `eval` here?  To me it seems like one of the few times where it is ok.

Comment: I wasn't fishing ;-) But since you asked, `eval` is not only avoided for its security risks when passed unsanitised values, but also for its poor performance. Although `eval` itself is slow (since it invokes the js compiler), it also makes the code around it slow. The reason for this is, where a compiler would normally make optimizations as it interprets code, it cannot know the result of the eval'd expression and therefore cannot make such optimizations.   There *are* uses for `eval`, but in the end it's the dev's decision to look at alternative solutions before taking the plunge.